# Filter integer result from Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql query. I want to filter only integer result.
My query is-

```
SELECT * FROM table as p WHERE p.test between 0 AND 999
```

But result comes this-

```
747
748
749
FO4001
FO4002
750
751
```

I want to ask two things-

1)Is there any way to exclude below result-

```
FO4001
FO4002
```

2)Why are these coming in the result?

Comment: What's the type of the column you are returning? String?

Comment: what Programming Language are you using?

Comment: `test` column is of varchar type and the programming is php.

Comment: @Irfan try using `REGEXP`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one, use `REGEXP` to test if the value is all numeric.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE x BETWEEN 0 AND 999
      AND x REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49c3f/19)

Comment: This will work for positive integer numbers but I believe this won't work with negative numbers or real numbers (because of the "-" and "."), also, this won't work on big numbers either because of the "e" of the exponential.

Comment: @LajosArpad [click here: added capability with negative numbers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cc4/1)